# trying to add an IP address to the end of the list in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have written a playbook that will be adding a new IP address to the list of IP address. This is the code

```
- name: adding IP to faile2ban
  lineinfile:
        path: /home/ec2-user/test.conf
        line: "{{ new_server_ip }}"
        insertafter: "^#?ip_list"
```

https://github.com/shettypriy/ansible/blob/master/addingIPto%20the%20end .The IP gets added to the file but it does not get added at the end of the last added IP

I have a file test.conf where IP address are added. I want to add the new IP after the last updated IP
Example: following is the sample content of the file test.conf

```
ip_list = xx.xx.xx.xx yy.yy.yy.zz aa.aa.aa.aa
```

My desired output should be 'new_server_ip' added after aa.aa.aa.aa

Comment: please help me on the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following should work for you well:

```
- name: adding IP to faile2ban
  lineinfile:
    dest: /home/ec2-user/test.conf
    state: present
    regexp: "^(#?ip_list(.*)$)"
    backrefs: yes
    line: '\1 {{ new_server_ip }}'
```

So the point is that you find row started with 'ip_list', select whole line by the regexp and then backrefencing selected row in your line in front of new_server_ip.

Comment: @user11549576 Glad to hear that! Please consider to accept my solution as 'answer' then :)

Answer (score 1):

The task below does the job and is [**idempotent**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#tasks-list)

> "Modules should be idempotent, that is, running a module multiple times in a sequence should have the same effect as running it just once."

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /home/ec2-user/test.conf
    regexp: '(?!.*{{ new_server_ip }}.*)^(ip_list.*)$'
    line: '\1 {{ new_server_ip }}'
    backrefs: yes
```

The *regexp* first [look ahead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) and 
 match the line only if *new_server_ip* is not present.